# Sending Gmail Schema Actions works from Gmail Scripts but not Mailgun

Tags: email, gmail, dkim, mailgun, google-schemas

I'm trying to send an email with a [Gmail Schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/one-click-action) embedded.  Currently, there is a restriction that says the schemas will only be visible if you [apply to be whitelisted](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1), but you can send emails from yourself to yourself to test.

I followed [Google's scripts tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial) and was able to get myself an email.  When I sent the exact same HTML email via mailgun, however, the Action does not become available in the inbox view.

[Email sent via Google Scripts](http://pastebin.com/kvyvnJC8)

vs

[Email sent via Mailgun](http://pastebin.com/Rhxu4kDj)

According to Google's requirements, we require DKIM, but from the headers it looks as if Mailgun provides them.  Mailgun clears out whitespace with =2Ds, but the Google Script doesn't.

Any ideas?  I've got a pending application for getting whitelisted, but in the meanwhile I'd like to be able to develop and iterate.

Comment: When using Mailgun is the email sent from your account and to your account? Is the DKIM signature for your domain or for Mailgun? The DKIM signature must match your domain in order for the whitelist to be ignored.

Comment: From my Gmail account to my Gmail account. Not 100% sure which DKIM signature Mailgun is using, but I'd guess it was for email_test.mailgun.com (I could see how that would be an issue).  

Any suggested workarounds? I imagine I shouldn't be able to use gmail's DKIM signature direcly, right?

Comment: You can use Gmail's DKIM signature if you connect directly to Gmail SMTP. Not sure if you can do that with Mailgun, I'd recommend asking them

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Google actions will work if you send an email to yourself; but aside from that, they will not work until your pending application has been approved and activated.

Even then, in your application it's required that you specify the address and domain that will be sending the emails, and that you have the proper authentication.  So even after you are approved, they will only work if you send from the domain and email address you requested approval for and as long as you still have the proper authentication measures in place.